# How to pass parameters to a cloudformation template which is embedded inside serverless.yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have a cloudformation template that I would like to embed in the resources section but the existing cloudformation template contains parameters. Is it possible to handle this?

resources: Resources: ${file(cloudformation-resources.yaml)}

I am trying to create IAM roles and Lambda functions using the template. and the template takes the environment name, security groupId, bucket name where the lambda code resides as passing as parameters. and I am using !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/ to get the log group inside the template.

But I am ending up with an error  " Invalid variable reference syntax for variable AWS::Region. You can only reference env vars, options, & files. You can check our docs for more info."

How can I handle this using serverless.yaml file.

Here is the serverless.yaml which i am trying

```
    service: sample
    frameworkVersion: ">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"
    plugins:
      - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  
  provider:
    name: aws
    stackName: "${opt:stackName,env:StackName}"
  parameters:
    SecurityGroupId: "${opt:SecurityGroupId,env:SecurityGroupId}"
    Subnets: "${opt:Subnets,env:Subnets}"
    environment: "${opt:environment,env:environment}"
    LambdacodeBucketName: "${opt:LambdacodeBucketName,env:LambdacodeBucketName}"
  resources:
  - ${file(test/template.yaml)}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it possible for u to do a nested stack or create the main stack and then use cloudformation outputs? here are a couple of links that can help

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html

Comment: Thanks @KerolosWilliam, But I need to achieve this using serverless